# Custom TextInputLayout does not show in preview

Tags: android, android-layout

I have custom textinputlayout in my login activity 
also in custom textinputlayout layout i have custom clearable edittext.

I can't see my custom textinputlayout in my login activity screen's preview but it's shown when i run the app on device.

Login Activity's xml

```
            <com.santsg.paximum.ui.customview.component.SpecialTextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/userNameEdt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:sethint="@string/user_name"/>

            <com.santsg.paximum.ui.customview.component.SpecialTextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/passwordEdt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:sethint="@string/password"/>
```

CustomTextInputLayout

```
public class SpecialTextInputLayout extends LinearLayout {

ClearableEditText editText;
TextInputLayout layout;
String hint;
public SpecialTextInputLayout(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public SpecialTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public SpecialTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs);
    LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.special_edittext_layout, this);
    initResource();

    TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ClearableEditText, defStyleAttr, 0);
    try {
        hint = ta.getString(R.styleable.ClearableEditText_sethint);
    } finally {
        ta.recycle();
    }

    layout.setHint(hint);
}

private void initResource() {
    editText = findViewById(R.id.specialEdt);
    layout = findViewById(R.id.specialEditLayout);
}

public void setText(String text) {
    editText.setText(text);
}

public String getText() {
    return editText.getText().toString();
}
```

Custom text input layout's xml.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/specialEditLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.EditText.Input">

    <com.santsg.paximum.ui.customview.component.ClearableEditText
        android:id="@+id/specialEdt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/clearable_edittext_input_height"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

and clearable edittext which is in special/custom text input layout.

```
ublic class ClearableEditText extends AppCompatEditText implements View.OnTouchListener, View.OnFocusChangeListener, TextWatcher {

private Drawable mClearTextIcon;
private OnFocusChangeListener mOnFocusChangeListener;
private OnTouchListener mOnTouchListener;

public ClearableEditText(final Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

public ClearableEditText(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public ClearableEditText(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    init(context);
}

@Override
public void setOnFocusChangeListener(final OnFocusChangeListener onFocusChangeListener) {
    mOnFocusChangeListener = onFocusChangeListener;
}

@Override
public void setOnTouchListener(final OnTouchListener onTouchListener) {
    mOnTouchListener = onTouchListener;
}

private void init(final Context context) {
    final Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, android.support.v7.appcompat.R.drawable.abc_ic_clear_material);
    final Drawable wrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable); //Wrap the drawable so that it can be tinted pre Lollipop
    DrawableCompat.setTint(wrappedDrawable, getCurrentHintTextColor());
    mClearTextIcon = wrappedDrawable;
    mClearTextIcon.setBounds(0, 0, mClearTextIcon.getIntrinsicHeight(), mClearTextIcon.getIntrinsicHeight());
    setClearIconVisible(false);
    super.setOnTouchListener(this);
    super.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
    addTextChangedListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onFocusChange(final View view, final boolean hasFocus) {
    if (hasFocus) {
        setClearIconVisible(getText().length() > 0);
    } else {
        setClearIconVisible(false);
    }
    if (mOnFocusChangeListener != null) {
        mOnFocusChangeListener.onFocusChange(view, hasFocus);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent motionEvent) {
    final int x = (int) motionEvent.getX();
    if (mClearTextIcon.isVisible() && x > getWidth() - getPaddingRight() - mClearTextIcon.getIntrinsicWidth()) {
        if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            setError(null);
            setText("");
        }
        return true;
    }
    return mOnTouchListener != null && mOnTouchListener.onTouch(view, motionEvent);
}

@Override
public final void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, final int start, final int before, final int count) {
    if (isFocused()) {
        setClearIconVisible(s.length() > 0);
    }
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
}


private void setClearIconVisible(final boolean visible) {
    mClearTextIcon.setVisible(visible, false);
    final Drawable[] compoundDrawables = getCompoundDrawables();
    setCompoundDrawables(
            compoundDrawables[0],
            compoundDrawables[1],
            visible ? mClearTextIcon : null,
            compoundDrawables[3]);
}
```

Comment: It's fine as long as you can see it on device.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto but it is really hard to design the screens in studio.

Comment: Maybe, layout_width / height are problem, you should try to spesific value for that. not match_parent

Comment: @MuhammedTayyibKılıç Thanks. temporarily it is a good solution, i can see just layout's space not the content but better than nothing, really helpful for creating the design.

Comment: you have height set as MATCH PARENT for each of your EDITTEXTS!

make them WrapContent it will try to wrap the View around your hint with some font padding ! you can add more padding if you like though!

Comment: @Rizwanatta It is not worked. probably because of the my sethint is custom attirubute.

Comment: then try weights! that would work!

Comment: any solution to this one? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

*Double Shift* to search on Android Studio, search for "Plugins".

[image: layout lib image]

install the two layout lib and restart android studio